# Google Cloud Dataflow: Session window with early firing trigger to limit session length

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am implementing session window withGapDuration = 10 mins and also put a limit on max number (100) of events a session can have. Any session longer than 100 elements will get split into multiple sessions.

By using Composite trigger and set Window Accumulation Mode to discardingFiredPanes(), it seems works.

I would like to get your opinion about this approach. Any unwanted side effect?

Thanks

```
//Ex: Session timeout 10 mins and max events session can have is 100. 
--skip
.triggering(
    Repeatedly.forever(
        AfterFirst.of( 
            AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(100), // max 100 events per session
            AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow() 
        )
    ) 
)
.discardingFiredPanes()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above will work, however it is better to do the following:

```
.triggering(
   AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(
      AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(100))
.discardingFiredPanes()
```

This is equivalent because `withEarlyFirings` will fire repeatedly when the triggering condition is met.

This is more efficient than using `AfterFirst.of` because it gives more information to the streaming dataflow runtime about what you want to do. Using `AfterFirst.of` dataflow does not know that the two triggering conditions are related. By using `withEarlyFirings` the dataflow runtime knows more and can optimize better for it. In practice, the code suggested here will be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: It is very strange. AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings() approach does not work for us. It seems is AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast() trigger either being ignore or runtime engine does not have the count of element yet? Is this unique to Sessions.withGapDuration window?

Comment: What is the symptom you are seeing? Are you getting Session windows with more than 100 elements? In general `elementCountAtLeast(N)` does not guarantee that it will be triggered exactly at N. So the session may be being triggered first.